# How to check if field has enough space for inserting data

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, record

I want to check if my field has enought space for inserting. So if field__c has enough space for data - it should be inserted into field__c. If not and field2__c has enough space it should be inserted into field2__c. I did it, but it looks too clumsy.

```
Integer len = SObjectType.Object__c.Fields.Field__c.Length;
Object__c obj = [Select id, field__c, field2__c from Object__c LIMIT 1];
String dataToInsert = 'text';
String objField1 = obj.field__c;
String objField2 = obj.field2__c;

if(len - objField.length() >= dataToInsert.length){
   obj.field__c + = 'text';
}
else if (len - objField2.length() >= dataToInsert.length) {
   obj.field2__c += 'text';
}
else {
   throw new CustomException();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be like below.

Replace the `object name(Account)` and `fields(Field1__C,Field2__C)` API names as per your org and run the below code in developer console.

```
// Get the length of the two fields
integer field1Length = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Field1__C.getLength();
integer field2Length = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Field2__C.getLength();

//initialize the string value
String dataToInsert = 'text data';

//initilize the acclist variable to store the object records
//Here i have taken account as an example
list<account> acclist = new list<account>();
// iterate the record using for loop
for(account acc: [select id,Field1__C,Field2__C from Account Limit 1]){
    
    if(field1Length>=dataToInsert.length()){        
      acc.Field1__C = dataToInsert; 
      acclist.add(acc); 
        
    } else if(field2Length>=dataToInsert.length()){
      acc.Field2__C = dataToInsert; 
      acclist.add(acc);  
    }
}
update acclist;
```

Comment: Thanks, its better.